# datepicker new date offset of 2 days

Tags: datepicker

im using [datepicker v2](http://kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/). And I have a question. Is there a possibility to let the currentdate have a offset of 2 days. For example; today is it 14may. Can i let the datepicker start today with 16may? And that 14&15 aren't selectable?

Greetz from Belgium

---

Is there a possibility for skipping the weekends with counting? For example; it is Saturday. So it has to be the Tuesday that will be selectable first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the days to the date before you cast it to a string.  Try changing

```
$(function()
{
    $('.date-picker').datePicker({clickInput:true}).val(new Date().asString()).addDays(2).trigger('change');
});
```

to

```
$(function()
{
    $('.date-picker').datePicker({clickInput:true}).val(new Date().addDays(2).asString()).trigger('change');
});
```

EDIT:  Sorry, didn't see the last requirement that today and tomorrow should not be selectable. Try

```
$(function()
{
    $('.date-picker').datePicker({clickInput:true, startDate: new Date().addDays(2).asString()}).val(new Date().addDays(2).asString()).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var twoDaysTijmeStr = (new Date()).addDays(2).asString;
$('.kalendertje')
    .val(twoDaysTijmeStr)
    .datePicker(
    {
        clickInput: true,
        startDate: twoDaysTijmeStr
    }
);
```

Let me know if you have any problems with it...

Answer (score 0):

works!

```
$(function()
{
    $('.date-picker').datePicker({clickInput:true}).val(new Date().addDays(2).asString()).trigger('change');
}
```

but the today-date is selectable.. i dont want that date to be selectable..

Comment: I just updated the example in my answer to reflect the further information here... You need to set a startDate as well as the selected date and setting the selected date shouldn't be necessary if you set the val on the input before calling the date picker...

Comment: dunnow where my answer is, but thanks again. it works fine! :)
now i had to do some changes so he doesn't count the weekends :p